# Whats the best way to parse/expand a REST API results with arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, rest, scripting

I have a result from a REST API call, that has a property which is a  JSON array.

What would be the best way to select a specific property out of that field.

The field looks like this:

values         : @{isForceAuth=false; tokenId=e3e944ee-059b-41c0-a7db-7969090e0722;successAuthMethods=identityProvider.embedded.authMethod.certificate; success=true;              destination=https://test.test.com/SAAS/API/1.0/GET/apps/launch/app/d22dd6b6a-4ac38b44686c1ec5f128appLaunchId=_b0f991454edfgfdgb6b0af2eb;authMethods=identityProvider.embedded.authMethod.certificate;actorExternalId=43f7d22f-84e4-46c2-83d9-1dhghfdfgce}

I've been trying to add it to an array with minimal success

Comment: Is `$result.values.isForceAuth` not working? If not, please show us your code :)

Comment: Nope that doesn't work at all. It's like you can't all that easily expand that array.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the real JSON response instead of the stringification: `$result | ConvertTo-Json`